# C++ standard: return by copy to initialize a reference without RVO: is there any copy?

Tags: c++, c++14, lifetime, rvo

Let's consider the next sample:

```
struct big_type {};

// Return by copy
auto factory() { return big_type{}; }

void any_scope_or_function() {
    big_type&& lifetime_extended = factory();
}
```

Under the assumption RVO is forbidden or not present at all and in any manner, will or can `big_type()` be copied? Or will the reference be directly bound to the temporary constructed within the `return` statement?

I want to be sure the `big_type` destructor is called only once when `any_scope_or_function` ends.

I use C++14, in case some behaviour has changed between standard's versions.

Comment: @NathanOliver I forgot to take out that compiler switch. Whoopsies.

Comment: Besides, I can't use C++17; C++14 at most.

Comment: @Peregring-lk but for the record.. this changed in C++17 which doesn't anymore require copy elision here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming there is no RVO/copy elison then in

```
auto factory() { return big_type{}; }
```

`big_type{}` is going to create a temporary `big_type`.  This object is then going to be used to *copy initialize* the object the function returns.  This means that the object you make in the function is going to be constructed and destructed.

With

```
big_type&& lifetime_extended = factory();
```

the rvalue reference will extend the lifetime of the functions return so we will see in total a default constructor call, a copy/move constructor call, and two destructor calls.

Now, if we change

```
auto factory() { return big_type{}; }
```

to

```
big_type factory() { return {}; }
```

then we are no longer creating a object in factory.  the return object is directly initialized with `{}` giving us in total a default constructor call and a destructor call

Answer (score 3):

> Or will the reference be directly bound to the temporary constructed
>   within the return statement?

No, it won't be. That's exactly what (N)RVO is about/for and you explicitly don't want that.

However, what will be attempted is using the move constructor of your `big_type`, which is technically not a copy. It does violate : "*`big_type` destructor is called only once when `any_scope_or_function` ends*" though since it'll be called twice.

GCC/Clang has a nice compiler switch : `-fno-elide-constructors` that disables (N)RVO which can be used for future reference. For now, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35817f1e2e13e122) is a test that has that option turned on, showing a double destructor call.